# Find the elementary matrix which performs a row operation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For a homework problem, I am required to find an elementary matrix ***E***_-2R_1+R_3 which performs the row operation ***R_3 = -2R_1+R_3*** on a given augmented matrix ***A*** = $$ \left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  2&6&2&0&0\\
  4&6&1&0&0\\
  -1&0&3&2&0
\end{array}
\right] $$ when it multiplies from the left side. I am also required to show methods for deriving it and and to give row operation notation for the reverse process.

Does this mean that I need to reduce the matrix to RREF to get E? To find the inverse using the reverse process, will I need to involve an identity matrix in any way?

Thank you in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Take an identity matrix and perform the operation.  Get $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\-2&0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

To get the reverse matrix, calculate the inverse.  Or, apply $2R_1+R_3$ to the identity, getting $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\2&0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you so much!